# Is it possible to nest function calls in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have the following css ID:

```
#SecondaryLayout__rightBgImg {
  background-image: "SOMETHING IS GOING TO BE HERE";
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

and I have the following HTML Element:

```
<div id="SecondaryLayout__rightBgImg">...</div>
```

I need to be able to set the background image from the HTML element, so what I did is that I changed the HTML element to the following:

```
<div id="SecondaryLayout__rightBgImg" img="/somewhere/photo.jpg">...</div>
```

and changed the css ID to the following:

```
#SecondaryLayout__rightBgImg {
  background-image: url(attr(img)); /* LOOK HERE */
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

However, this `url(attr(img))` isn't working.

but why? and is it possible to nest function calls in css? what is the better approach for this case?

Comment: Are use using this for a class or an id only? If this is for a single element could you not just specify the URL directly in the css rather than using the `attr()` function?

Comment: attr used in anything other than content does not seem to be supported by any browser yet see https://caniuse.com/?search=attr Is there a reason for not setting it in a style attribute?

Comment: @DanielBlack, actually the problem is over complicated way than that. I am using React (JSX) with Redux, but this was the portion of the problem that happened while I was developing in React

Comment: For my code case, Since I am using React (JSX), I can specify the style property directly on the HTML element itself, and then I can add the background-image url there by specifying the changing variable there. If you say it's complicated and not recommended, then I'll just go and do that. but I was just thinking if it was possible to abstract the styling code from the logical programmatic part.